# Correct Syntax For Preparing MySQL INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have been troubleshooting my code, searching stackoverflow to find the correct syntax to do this with PHP. I can't figure out how the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE syntax works with prepared statements:

```
INSERT INTO placements_by_date (DateVal, PlacementName, PlacementId, 
CampaignId, AdName, Format, TagId, Impressions, Clicks, Leads, MediaCost) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
// HERE COMES THE TRICKY SYNTAX: 
DateVal = VALUES(DateVal), PlacementName = VALUES(PlacementName), 
PlacementId = VALUES(PlacementId), CampaignId = VALUES(CampaignId), 
AdName = VALUES(AdName), Format = VALUES(Format), TagId = VALUES(TagId), 
Impressions = ?, Clicks = ?, Leads = ?, MediaCost = ?
```

I have tried many variations:

```
...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
DateVal = VALUES('$DateVal'), PlacementName = VALUES('$PlacementName'), 
PlacementId = VALUES('$PlacementId'), CampaignId = VALUES('$CampaignId'), 
AdName = VALUES('$AdName'), Format = VALUES('$Format'), TagId = VALUES('$TagId'),
Impressions = VALUES(?), Clicks = VALUES(?), Leads = VALUES(?), 
MediaCost = VALUES(?)";
```

I store this as a string, `$sql`, and do my usual stuff:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(...
...
$stmt = $mysqli -> prepare($sql);
$stmt -> bind_param('sissiiiis', $PlacementName, $PlacementId, 
                     $AdName, $Format, $TagId, $Impressions, 
                     $Clicks, $Leads, $MediaCost);
...
```

But maybe the parameters should be bound differently??

I enabled tried reading through the feedback but this was too generic with no actionable insights.

```
$driver = new mysqli_driver();
$driver->report_mode = MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL;
```

Hoping you have some insight to share?

Thanks!

Comment: Your syntax in the top example looks right, but I count 15 `?` placeholder while you only have ~10 in `bind_param('sissiiiis'...)`. You need to account for every placeholder in the `bind_param()` even if it is repeated.

Comment: Did you `echo $driver->error;`  after calling `prepare()`? Did you check that `$stmt` succeeded and check for errors after `bind_param()`?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: I get this: **exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement'**

Comment: Yes, that's what I would expect --because you had more `?` in the statement than you had parameters passed into `bind_param()`.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: Thanks for getting back. If I have strictly less `?` in the statements compared to bound parameters I get  **exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'Column count doesn't match value count at row 1'**. If I have strictly more, I get the same message. If I have exactly the right number I get **exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement'**.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski your comments really helped me to understand using prepared statements where nothing else I've found in 4 days searching on SO did - you should put them into an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Why not continue using the `VALUES()` method?

```
INSERT INTO placements_by_date(DateVal, PlacementName, PlacementId, 
                               CampaignId, AdName, Format, TagId,
                               Impressions, Clicks, Leads, MediaCost
                              ) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
        DateVal = VALUES(DateVal), PlacementName = VALUES(PlacementName), 
        PlacementId = VALUES(PlacementId), CampaignId = VALUES(CampaignId), 
        AdName = VALUES(AdName), Format = VALUES(Format), TagId = VALUES(TagId), 
        Impressions = VALUES(Impressions), Clicks = VALUES(Clicks), Leads = VALUES(Leads),
        MediaCost = VALUES(MediaCost);
```

You don't specify what the `unique` key is.  However, you don't need to include those columns in the `update` statements, because they are already the same.

If, perchance, you want to *increment* the last four values rather than just assign them, you can do that too:

```
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
        DateVal = VALUES(DateVal), PlacementName = VALUES(PlacementName), 
        PlacementId = VALUES(PlacementId), CampaignId = VALUES(CampaignId), 
        AdName = VALUES(AdName), Format = VALUES(Format), TagId = VALUES(TagId), 
        Impressions = Impressions + VALUES(Impressions),
        Clicks = Clicks + VALUES(Clicks),
        Leads = Leads + VALUES(Leads),
        MediaCost = MediaCost + VALUES(MediaCost)
```

EDIT:

The following should work just to update the last four columns:

```
INSERT INTO placements_by_date(DateVal, PlacementName, PlacementId, 
                               CampaignId, AdName, Format, TagId,
                               Impressions, Clicks, Leads, MediaCost
                              ) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
        Impressions = VALUES(Impressions), Clicks = VALUES(Clicks), Leads = VALUES(Leads),
        MediaCost = VALUES(MediaCost);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick and elaborate answer. The `unique` key is the  combination of `DateVal` and `TagId` but from the data structure I am guaranteed that only `Impressions`, `Clicks`, `Leads` and `MediaCost` will change. Tried removing the others from the `ON DUPLICATE...`-part but it still does not work. Any ideas?